# a problem with the raylib installation on linux

Tags: c++, c, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, raylib

im using Peppermint 10 an ubuntu based distro

so i did the following commands [here](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-GNU-Linux#build-raylib-using-cmake) and everything went well until this

```
(the input)

cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..

(the output)

-- Testing if -Werror=pointer-arith can be used -- compiles

-- Testing if -Werror=implicit-function-declaration can be used -- compiles

-- Testing if -fno-strict-aliasing can be used -- compiles

-- Using raylib's GLFW

-- Using X11 for window creation

-- Audio Backend: miniaudio

-- Building raylib shared library

-- Generated build type: Debug

-- Compiling with the flags:

-- PLATFORM=PLATFORM_DESKTOP

-- GRAPHICS=GRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33

-- Building examples is enabled

-- Testing if -std=c11 can be used -- compiles

-- Configuring done

CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:57 (add_library):

Error evaluating generator expression:


$<TARGET_OBJECTS:glfw>


Objects of target "glfw" referenced but is not an OBJECT library.



CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: raylib

CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "raylib".

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/anas/raylib/build
```

how do i even fix these cmake errors?

but then i ignored these thought it was normal but when i tried to do the following command

```
(the command aka the input)

make

(the output)

[ 7%] Built target glfw

make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/build'. Stop.

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:87: recipe for target 'raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/all' failed

make[1]: *** [raylib/CMakeFiles/raylib.dir/all] Error 2

Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

it shows the same thing when i try  `sudo make install`

help
i still dont know what is the problem here
btw im following the wiki [here](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-on-GNU-Linux)

Comment: Hi, do not bother with raylib installation. If you want to start promptly game project use cmake template for C: https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/tree/master/projects/CMake or for C++: https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp/tree/master/projects/CMake. CMake will download correct version of raylib for you. To my first project I used https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp/tree/master/projects/CMake with no issues.

Comment: but how can i add the template to my pc?

Comment: how do i even run it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

0. sudo apt install g++
1. sudo apt install cmake (should be in version 3.11 or higher)
2. download to your project folder ex. 'new-game' folder those three files from https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp/tree/master/projects/CMake (main.cpp, README.md, CMakeLists.txt)
3. then `cd new-game && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`
4. run `./raylib-cpp-example`

Comment: but i want to use c for the raylib thing

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I try to build raylib on Ubuntu 18.04. There is no such problem on 20.04 and 22.04.

I found a solution:

Edit `cmake/GlfwImport.cmake` file by replacing

```
list(APPEND raylib_sources $<TARGET_OBJECTS:glfw>)
```

with:

```
list(APPEND raylib_sources external/glfw/include/GLFW/glfw3.h)
```